# If $|G|=k$, then $a^k=e$ for every $a \in G$

Tags: group-theory

I have a theorem here that says:

> Let G be a finite group. If $|G|=k$, then $a^k=e$ for every $a \in G$.

How is this seen?

Comment: Look up a proof of Lagrange's theorem, or look for that in the textbook

Comment: Note that order of an element is the order of the subgroup generated by that element. By Langrange's theorem we know that order of a subgroup divides the order of a group.

Answer (score 0):

Let $O(a)=n$ we have $H=<a>=\{e,a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1}\}$. H is subgroup of G therefore $|H|\left| \,|G| \right.$because $|G|=|H|[G:H]$ as a result $a^k=e$

Comment: Where's it said that $H$ is cyclic?

Comment: I define $H=\{a^i\,|\,i\in\,Z\,\}$